# run time error 91 object variable or with block not set

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

Getting the above run time error while executing the code second time. First time it is executing successfully. I have attached the code to which it points when I go to Debug mode. Please help to resolve this issue.
Code:-

```
    wbExcel.Worksheets("No of risks per user").Activate
    wbExcel.ActiveSheet.UnProtect Password:="pwd1"
    wbExcel.ActiveSheet.Columns("M:M").Select     
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False  ' It points to this line in debug mode 
    Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Comment: can you show more code `wbExcel`?

Comment: if you're running this code form Access, then the plain `Selection` reference will point to Access `Selection` object (whatever it might be). To reference the Excel sheet columns selections than you have to go as per @L42 answer

Comment: You should avoid using `.Activate`, `.Select` and other `Selection.` when possible. See [How to avoid using select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything out of the ordinary except referencing issue. You might want to try below and see if it will generate the same error.

```
With wbExcel.Worksheets("No of risks per user")
    .UnProtect Password:="pwd1"
    .Columns("M").Hidden = False
    .Columns("M").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    .Columns("M").Hidden = True
End With
```